# Can $I_n = \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{t^2-t^4} P_1^0(t) P_n^0(t) dt$ be evaluated analytically where $P_n^m$ are the associated Legendre polynomials?

Tags: integration, special-functions, orthogonality, spherical-coordinates, legendre-polynomials

I have arrived at the following integral. I would like to know if it is possible integrate it analytically as if not I will have to numerically integrate it:
$$
I_n = \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{t^2-t^4} P_1^0(t) P_n^0(t) dt,
$$
where $P_n^m$ are the associated Legendre polynomials.

Comment: Why associated Legendre polynomials? For even $n$ you have $I_{2m}=0$ because $P_{2m}$ is even and your integrand is odd.

Comment: @gammatester I'm not sure what you mean by 'Why associated Legendre polynomials?'

Comment: Because you actually use only the ordinary Legendre polynomials (ie upper index 0)

Comment: @gammatester Oh yes your correct, I was originally using the associated Legendre polynomials but they reduced to this form after some manipulation!